# Python Longest list in a list of lists; with empty list support

Tags: python, list

So many threads already talk about returning the longest list in a list of lists by

```
max(sorted(lst_of_lsts, key = len))
```

But this spews if lst_of_lsts is an empty list.

> ```
> max(sorted(lst_of_lsts, key = len)) ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
> ```

Is there a version with support for empty lists?  It would return an empty list.

Thanks

Comment: Can't we use `try:.. except ValueError:`?

Comment: Please add sample input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your original is incorrect. `max` does not require a sorted argument, and even if you do sort it, you still have to pass `key` to `max`. Here is an example of what happens if you don't: https://ideone.com/TMJyGK.

The easiest thing I can think of is to just check if your list is empty:

```
max(lst_of_lst if lst_of_lst else [[]], key=len)
```

OR

```
max(lst_of_lst, key=len) if lst_of_lst else []
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add the list by `[[]]`:

```
max(lst_of_lsts + [[]], key = len)
```

Comment: I didn't knew we can use 'key' in `max`

Comment: This works too; and is the one I used; I just can't have two answers. So I accepted them chronologically. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
lst_of_lsts = [[], []]
lst = sorted(lst_of_lsts, key = len)[0]
if lst:
    print(max(lst))
else:
    print() #whatever
```